# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout Children

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hej,

i created a custom ViewCell with a grid and some labels. Just trying to understand Xamarin.Forms, if i want to add my custom ViewCell to a StackPanel it wont work becuase **`StackLayout.Children.Add()`** only accepts Views.

Am i missing something ?

**Custom ViewCell**

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="22*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="4" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="5" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="6" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="7" TextColor="Black"/>
  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

and in my code behind im trying to add my custom ViewCell with **`StackLayout.Children.Add(CustomViewCellObj)`**

Comment: Cells are only used in Lists and Tables.  Try using a ContentView instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Is there any way how i could add my ViewCell wich is basicly just like a ListView Cell to my Stacklayout ? Or is there a better way for solving?

Comment: create a custom class that inherits from ContentView.  Place your Grid and it's contents inside.  Now you have a custom control that you can use in a StackLayout.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your Help.